# Typing dynamic import

Tags: typescript, dynamic-import

I have a function that dynamically import a bunch of files given a directory path. However, I'm scratching my head on how I would type this.

```js
export const fileHandler = async (
  dirPath: string
) => {
  // the list of js/ts files within the directory
  const files = readdirSync(dirPath).filter(
    (f) => f.endsWith('.js') || f.endsWith('.ts'),
  );

  for (const file of files) {
    const resolvePath = path.join(dirPath, file);

    // type ModuleType = Promise<typeof import(resolvePath)>; // String literal expected.
    
    const defaultImport = (await import(resolvePath)).default; // Unsafe member access .default on an any value

    // do something with it...
  }
}
```

I understand that `import(...)` wants a static path for safe typing. But how do I type import while allowing the function to accept any directory path.

Comment: What do you want the type to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

Since `dirPath` and `resolvePath` are dynamic (only known at runtime), the  `import(resolvePath)` type is also only available at runtime. That is why TypeScript was complaining about type safety and wants a static path.

If you know the file type of the files you're dynamically importing

```js
const myFile: FileType = {
  foo: 'FOO',
  bar: 'BAR'
}
export default myFile;
```

you can type cast it

```js
type ModuleType = {default: FileType};
const defaultImport = (await import(resolvePath) as FileType).default
```